# Excel Index Indirect closed workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am aware that you can not use Indirect to reference a closed workbook, but you can use the index function to return a value from a closed workbook such as:

=INDEX([Test.xlsx]Sheet1!C:C,14,1)

returns the value from cell C14

The indirect function also works fine, when the workbook is open;
=INDIRECT("'"&$F6&"'!C14")

For the life of me i can not seem to combine the two to get my desired result, that being the value from the closed workbook.

Am I missing something or is this not possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting value from a closed workbook with a formula is **not possible**.

As a workaround, you may create VBA code, which opens the workbook, takes the value and closes it. This is some example code, which opens the file `testing.xlsx` and writes the value of `Worksheets(1).Range("A1")` to `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\path\testing.xlsx")
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A3") = GetSheet1A1(wb)
    wb.Close False

End Sub

Public Function GetSheet1A1(wb As Workbook) As Variant

    GetSheet1A1 = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value2

End Function
```

Comment: There is INDIRECT.EXT but caution should be offered about the source of the code.

Comment: @Jeeped - I have never used the `INDIRECT.EXT`, but I guess it is still openning the referenced workbook. Otherwise I cannot imagine how it is done.

Comment: It's from an old open source add-in. The problem with finding a copy is that there are many bastardized copies floating around.

Comment: @Jeeped - you mean these nicely locked VBA add-ins, which nicely start sending information about your files and actions to a specific email/db.